# Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-support:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am getting below error while building the source code.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE: Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-support:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

---

Using release 2.2.6

Repository: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot.git

commands used for build, after cloning the tag:

cd spring-boot-project/spring-boot/

mvn clean install

Comment: The given dependency `spring-boot-test-support` does not exist...

Comment: Here is the solution: spring-boot-test-support is an unpublished support module that must be built and installed locally before you can build individual modules. the module is available in spring-boot/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-test-support/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: 
`spring-boot-test-support` is an unpublished support module that must be built and installed locally before you can build individual modules. 
the module is available in `spring-boot/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-test-support/` directory